# How to create chain of dynamic proxies?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I create two InvocationHandler, one for logging purpose and the other one for measuring time. Each on works but I do not know how to create a chain of these two, so that both will be executed. I thought it would be enough that for example the LoggingInvocationHandler extends the TimerInvocationHandler

```
    public class DynamicProxyMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Starting dynamic proxy sample");

    SubjectInterface timerProxy = (SubjectInterface) Proxy.newProxyInstance(SubjectInterface.class.getClassLoader(),
            new Class<?>[]{SubjectInterface.class},
            new TimerInvocationHandler(new SubjectInterfaceImpl()));

    SubjectInterface logginProxy = (SubjectInterface) Proxy.newProxyInstance(SubjectInterface.class.getClassLoader(),
            new Class<?>[]{SubjectInterface.class},
            new LoggingInvocationHandler(new SubjectInterfaceImpl()));
    timerProxy.methodA("a");
    timerProxy.methodB("test b");
    timerProxy.methodC(1, "test c");

}
}

public class LoggingInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {
Object impl;
String CLASSNAME = this.getClass().getCanonicalName();

public LoggingInvocationHandler(Object impl){
    this.impl = impl;

}
public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
    Object retVal;
    System.out.println("LoggingHandler:" + this.getClass().getName() + " has been called");
    retVal = method.invoke(impl, args);
    System.out.println("LoggingHandler:" + this.getClass().getName() + " has ended");
    return retVal;

}
}


 public class TimerInvocationHandler extends LoggingInvocationHandler          implements InvocationHandler{
private Object impl;

public TimerInvocationHandler(Object impl) {
    super(impl);
    this.impl = impl;
}

public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {

    Object retVal = null;
    System.out.println("getting duration time for method " + method.getName());
    long duration = -System.currentTimeMillis();
    retVal = super.invoke(proxy,method,args);
    duration += System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("it took " + duration + " milliseconds");
    System.out.println("duration time handler has ended");
    return retVal;
}
}
```

Actually I solved it, so that both InvocationHandlers will be called. I edited my post with the currently working code

Comment: Can you show us how you've implemented your handlers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea bears a similarity to `Intercepting Filter`, I'll give your an implementation of it, which slightly modified in order to work with `DynamicProxyHandler`, if you're interested and want more details, you should read the [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/interceptingfilter-142169.html) thoroughly.

**Participants**:

- `InvocationChain` - which is responsible for dispatching invocations.
- `Invocation` - where you should put things like `logging` and `timer`.
- `DynamicProxyHanlder` - that simply delegates the request to `InvocationChain`.

**Implementaiton**:

*DynamicProxyHandler.java*

```
public class DynamicProxyHandler implements InvocationHandler {
    private Object proxied;
    InvocationChain chain = new InvocationChainImp();

    DynamicProxyHandler(Object proxied) {
        this.proxied = proxied;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        return chain.invoke(proxied, method, args);
    }

}
```

*Invocation.java*

```
public interface Invocation {
    Object invoke(Object callee, Method method, Object[] args, InvocationChain chain);
}
```

*InvocationChain.java*

```
public interface InvocationChain {
    public Object invoke(Object callee, Method method, Object[] args);
}
```

*InvocationChainImp.java*

```
public class InvocationChainImp implements InvocationChain {
    List<Invocation> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Object result;
    Iterator<Invocation> tasks;

    InvocationChainImp() {
        list.add(new LoggingInvocation());
        list.add(new TimerInvocation());
        list.add(new FinalInvocation());
        tasks = list.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object callee, Method method, Object[] args) {
        if (tasks.hasNext()) {
            Object result = tasks.next().invoke(callee, method, args, this);
            this.result = (this.result == null ? result : this.result);
        }
        return this.result;
    }
```

Last not least, we want to define some custom classes that must be confined to `Invocation` interface for logging, timer, etc.

*LoggingInvocation.java*

```
public class LoggingInvocation implements Invocation {
    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object callee, Method method, Object[] args, InvocationChain chain) {
        chain.invoke(callee, method, args);
        Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getCanonicalName()).info(method.getName() + "() execution logged!");
        return null;
    }
}
```

*TimerInvocation.java*

```
public class TimerInvocation implements Invocation {
    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object callee, Method method, Object[] args, InvocationChain chain) {
        long start_time = System.nanoTime();
        chain.invoke(callee, method, args);
        long end_time = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println("Timer: excution took " + (end_time - start_time) / 1e6 + "ms");

        return null;
    }
}
```

*FinalInvocation.java* where the request is finally invoked on the proxied instance.

```
public class FinalInvocation implements Invocation {
    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object callee, Method method, Object[] args, InvocationChain chain) {
        try {
            return method.invoke(callee, args);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Rest of code is trivial, as it's just used to prove that the implementation works.
**You can stop reading now** if want to write your own.

*SubjectInterface.java*

```
public interface SubjectInterface {
    String hello();
}
```

*SubjectInterfaceImp.java*

```
public class SubjectInterfaceImp implements SubjectInterface {
    @Override
    public String hello() {
        System.out.println("in SubjectInterfaceImp: Greeting!");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

*Main.java*

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SubjectInterface subject = (SubjectInterface) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                SubjectInterface.class.getClassLoader(),
                new Class[] { SubjectInterface.class }, new DynamicProxyHandler(new SubjectInterfaceImp()));
        System.out.println("in Main: subject.hello() = " + subject.hello());
    }
}
```

Okay, we have enough of code, **it's show time, let's see we got**, *voila*!

```
in SubjectInterfaceImp: Greeting!
Timer: excution took 0.532198ms
九月 02, 2016 12:37:36 下午 LoggingInvocation invoke
信息: hello() execution logged!
in Main: subject.hello() = hello
```

Comment: The order of Invocation is very **important**, for example, if `TimerInvocation` is called first, the result could be inaccurate, as it includes time spent on subquent invocations.

Comment: Thanks for your extensively answer, it sounded promising so I tried to refactor my solution with your instructions. Currently I stuck on two problems. First the real methods will not be called and second the chain will only work the first round, because the iterator is on the last item when the first invocation has been called, so the next round it finds no hasNext. I published my attempt to Github if you want to check https://github.com/crojay78/PatternPlayground

Comment: I made some changes, so now it works as expected. I injected the proxied object to the InvocationChainImpl. As soon as there are no invocationhandlers in the list, then the real method will be called an the tasks will be set to the initial value. If you are interested you can check the github project, feel free to optimize :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is not the natural way to implement it.TimerInvocationHandler has nothing to do with LoggingInvocationHandler.
define a decorator which is a InvocationHandler and wraps a another InovovationHandler

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

EDIT: since one comment ask me to provide a sample implementation,following part is added, but this is the not exact decorator pattern, but i think others can understand the solution. in this case TimeInvocationHandler is not limited to measure the login time

```
public class TimerInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler
{
  protected InvocationHandler invocationHandler;

  @Override
  public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable
  {
    //do whatever you want
    Object result = invocationHandler.invoke(proxy, method, args);
    // do what ever you want
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: this can be a comment or you need to edit to make it possible answer

Comment: @ Asterisk Ninja - what are you talking about